# Creating own editor type

Tags: scripting

Is it possible to create your own editor type with python? I know that I can edit the sources of existing ones like the INFO header. But I want to create a complete new one where I can place my operators.

Comment: what is an editor type? can you eleborate.

Comment: I mean the windows like 3D view or graph editor. Maybe its also called area.type

Comment: It is refered to as *Editor* as well as *Space type*. I wouldn't call it *Area type*, 'cause an area is a generic type and does not store any Editor/Space related data (other than the type and references to the regions and spaces). An `area.type` is set to use a certain Editor or Space type for that area in Python.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See [API docs - Preface](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_10/info_quickstart.html):

> The Blender/Python API can’t (yet)...
>
> - Create new space types.

It can only be done in the C code:
http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.6/Source/Tutorials/AddAnEditor

Nonetheless,

- you may use [draw handlers](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/API_Changes#Region_Draw_Callbacks_.28r53207.29) to overlay an existing editor with python-drawn content. Check out [OpenGL Wrapper (bgl)](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_10/bgl.html) and [Font Drawing (blf)](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_10/blf.html).
- or build blender with the Py-Buttons patch by Campbell Barton to create python-drawn widgets:
  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mRiTfLpRlRU
  (seems to crash if applied to current trunk, use an older revision or wait for a fix)