# How to add header and space choice combobox to a custom made space?

Tags: python, add-on

I followed the tutorial for making a custom space in C code, from the tutorial in this question [Creating own editor type](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7055/creating-own-editor-type).

I succeeded but it seems that it has no header and no combo box with the list of other spaces. If I try to run template scripts to create panels and switch the `bl_space_type` to the name of my editor the script runs with no errors but the controls don't show up.
So I am interested in how to insert header, combo box and generally make it work like other spaces with the Python API.
A python based solution is preferable but, at this point, I would welcome any.

Comment: While there is some discussion to [allow blender development questions](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2216/935), the C/C++ development of blender is still [considered off topic here](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6/935).

Comment: Okay, I will be sure to remember that, hopefully, I can achieve everything I want to, without editing more C/C++ code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how much of this is necessary but I did some intuitive edits on the code and it works, if anyone can explain exactly why I would be most grateful.

Go to the `/home/user/blender-git/build_linux/bin/2.79/scripts/startup/bl_ui`(respective to your system) folder where all the other editor `*.py` startup files are copy `space_info.py`, rename it to `space_yourspace.py`.

In the same folder find the `__init__.py` open it and add `space_yourspace` to the constant `_modules`, this will make blender run said module on startup, so be sure to edit the file before starting it up.

Now open up `space_yourspace.py` and delete everything from         `INFO_MT_editor_menus.draw_collapsible(context, layout)` down to, but not including `classes = (`.

Now in the classes tuple delete everything except `INFO_HT_header`, be sure to leave one comma after `INFO_HT_header` so it remains a tuple and not just a pair of parenthesis. Rename `INFO_HT_header` to `YOURSPACE_OT_header` in the tuple.

Go back to the remaining `class` and rename it also to `YOURSPACE_OT_header`.Inside the `class` change the value of static variable `bl_space_type` to `'YOURSPACE_EDITOR'`.
After this, you can start Blender and in the header of `yourspace` you will have the said combo box.

Comment: While the main area of an editor is implemented in C/C++, all of the UI widgets are controlled using python. The `bl_ui/space_yourspace.py` is the file blender finds to use for a `yourspace` editor, without it there are no regions displayed around the editor. Similar naming conventions are used to find the code to use - `YOURSPACE_HT_header` for the header, while `bl_space_type` needs to be set for panels that belong to that editor, this is the same as setting it for any custom panels you add to existing editors.