# How to divide area into a new region(with python)?

Tags: python, scripting, video-sequence-editor, panel

In an attempt to figure out if it is possible to add channel headers to the Sequencer with python, the first step is to figure out how to divide the sequencer area(add a new region).

**How do I divide the sequencer area like the NLA editor, so there is a region for adding channel headers on the lefthand side of the Sequencer?**

Like this:
[image]

(And eventually, add scaleable view/hide, mute/unmute, color, lock/unlock functions etc. to the new "panel" area.)

NB. I'm not after splitting the area into two separate areas like this: https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?333636-Windows-Areas-and-Screens-with-Python&p=2624709&viewfull=1#post2624709

Comment: Not sure that's possible. You can do some type of bgl overlay.  Here is a pic of a [bgl overlay for graph editor (bottom of area, rather that LHS)](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/batFINGER/batFINGER-blender-addons/images/midi2.png)  The link I pointed out in blf answer shows how the frame and the channel can be used to get x, y coordinates of area.  The "rub" is, I've heard some talk that bgl is going to be dropped for something new, which leaves it up in the air somewhat.  If your C/C++ skills are Ok could patch in a new region.

Comment: Wow, that's cool with the keyboard interface for midi.Thanks for letting me know about the limitations and the potential developments.

Comment: This touches on the subject: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7055/creating-own-editor-type/7056#7056