# How add editor type like "COMPOSITOR"

Tags: scripting, add-on

There is already an [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/7056/78950) to the question whether it is possible to create your own editor type, but my question is more SPECIFIC and also the answer to this question is very OLD. I want to find out how to create editor type as a compositor. For example, there is addons like "Animation Nodes" or "Socar" and they add their editor type like compositor to Blender.

Comment: Have a look into the templates that come with blender: *Text Editor > Templates > Python > Custom Nodes*.

Comment: @brockmann with a bit more explanation that would be a perfect answer to the question.